# trying to update ENUM, then I got NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

```
public class Trade extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long tradeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "commission_id")
    private Commission commission;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Member member;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMTEXT")
    private String content;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.Waiting_Acceptance;
```

```
public enum Status {
    Waiting_Acceptance("수락대기"),
    In_Progress("진행 중"),
    Done("완료");

    @Getter
    @JsonValue
    private final String krName;

    Status(String krName) {
        this.krName = krName;
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TradePatchDto {

    @NotNull(message = "요청을 확인해주세요")
    private Status status;
}
```

I just wanna test update the default status of post to other status like In_progress or Done.

but when I test on Postman like this

```
{
    "status" : "진행 중"
}
```

I always got NPE

What did I miss?? I'm a novice so I cannot find the problem

also I searched about this, I cannot find the solution please help me

Comment: You posted your data, but you'll need to post the code of the actual functionality in which the NPE occurs. My guess would be that you transfer a `String` and haven't configured a way to transfer it to the `enum` (like `valueOf`), but from this we don't even know if the exception happens in the controller or the repository. tl;dr [mcve] please.

Comment: The value you are sending isn't a valid enum value. It is the internal string you give instead of the name of the enum. So it converts to nothing. Either write your own custom converter or send the proper name .

Comment: Can you show us what look like your table "Trade" ? is your status column write in english or with korean name (krName attribute) ?